# Stored procedure for writing back to db2 database

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, plsql, db2

Im new to db2 stored procedure, im approaching here for some help/guidance.
I have users who access cognos for reporting.
Recently I got a requirement from one of our clients for writing back to the db2 table based on user provided comment or input through IBM cognos.

I tried below code in db2 and cognos, but it works half way.
The catch is whenever a user provides a fresh entry it gets stored quickly but whenever a user tries to update the same entry, it takes almost 15-20 mins to refresh that record at table level. I won't understand what i can improve on my code here.

```
create procedure ngetl.new_update_comment (
        in @p_job_status_summary_key integer
        ,in @p_comment varchar(4000)
        ,in @p_modified_by varchar(25)
      )
    dynamic result sets 1
begin
  declare e1 cursor with return for
    select 1
      from ngetl.job_status_summary
      where job_status_summary_key = 17076
      with ur;
  if upper(@p_modified_by) like '%IBM%'
    or upper(@p_modified_by) like 'V%' then
    update ngetl.job_status_summary
      set ibm_comment = @p_comment
          ,modified_by_ibm = @p_modified_by
          ,timestamp_ibm = current_timestamp
      where job_status_summary_key = @p_job_status_summary_key;
  else update ngetl.job_status_summary
    set sbi_comment = @p_comment
        ,modified_by_sbi = @p_modified_by
    where job_status_summary_key = @p_job_status_summary_key;
  end if;
  commit;
  open e1;
end
```

Comment: can anybody help pls ?

Comment: Did I get you right that when you call this SP directly (not as part of some Cognos report along with some other code potentially) for the 1-st time then it works quick, but if you call it with the same parameters again, it takes 15-20 mins to complete? If yes, then have you tried to remember the current session's application handle before the call with the `MON_GET_APPLICATION_HANDLE ()` function and use `SELECT * 
FROM TABLE (MON_GET_AGENT(NULL , NULL, <saved_app_handle> , -2))` to check the state of the call? If yes, then what's the result of a couple of subsequent calls in, say, 10 sec?

Comment: Hey Mark, let me try this scalar function to check the state of SP call. Thanks!